# Beans for third party library in spring-config.xml

Tags: java, spring

I have a class looking like below

```
@Component
public class BillDAO {

    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    public void create(BillDO billDO) {
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1);
        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(builder.build());
        dynamoDBMapper.save(billDO);
    }
}
```

Basically, I don't want to construct dynamoDBMapper and builder instance every time I call the method create. Rather like to inject these as beans. What can be done?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tarkshala" />
</beans>
```

I did find few example which use constructor-arg for beans and factory-methods. Not sure how to use that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to make use of **[@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)** annotation to do this. Here is the code example of **@Configuration** implementation to create both **AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder & DynamoDBMapper** as Spring 
beans.

```
package com.tarkshala;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationAnnotationExample {

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder getAmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1);
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper getDynamoDBMapper(final AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder) {
        return new DynamoDBMapper(builder.build());
    }
}
```

Here is your modified BillDAO to make use of injected DynamoDBMapper.

```
package com.tarkshala;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BillDAO {

    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Autowired
    public BillDAO(final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper) {
        this.dynamoDBMapper = dynamoDBMapper;
    }

    public void create(BillDO billDO) {
        dynamoDBMapper.save(billDO);
    }
}
```

Since you already added the **`<context:component-scan base-package="com.tarkshala"/>`** in your application context xml, nothing more is required to create beans from ConfigurationAnnotationExample class.

Comment: getDynamoDBMapper function seems to be creating new DynamoDBMapper instance every time. Right? I want it to reuse the bean.

Comment: getDynamoDBMapper will be called only once when the ApplicationContext is created. Hence its going to be single bean that will be present in the ApplicationContext.